# How to merge Xpath text if there is 1 more subtag with text?

Tags: xpath

Sometimes there is a span inside a tag that breaks the text, how do I get text1+text2 as one argument? And tell me if it is possible to clear the text from spaces.
my locator: `html.xpath('//div[@class="divclass"]/a/text()')`

`.../a')` return []

```
<div class="divclass">
<a>
text1
<span></span>
text2
</a>
</div>
```